# How to broadcast image over ble dual mode

Tags: c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, file-transfer

I have two Bluetooth 4.0 dual mode devices. Is it possible to do the following

1. Connect via BLE to transfer state information then
2. Switch connection to Bluetooth Classic/EDR to transfer large file means image (to be done without user interaction) after transfer of the file
3. Back to BLE

Answer (score 0):

The chips are capable of working with BT/BLE simultaneously, so I don't see why you couldn't. Now, it will really depend on what device you are working with, and what software is available to you. There should be no need to switch from one to another (at least not on a modern OS like iOS or Android). It may be different on a electronic project for example, but that won't be a BT/BLE limitation.

Quick note if you plan to work with iOS: Keep in mind that custom transfers with Classic BT is not available on iOS without the "Made For iPhone" program. Which you will not get easily (and not for free I beleive).

Comment: I appreciate your response i am using nRF51822 and trying to transfer image if i use BT mode then consumption of power is high that's why i am using ble mode to find new devices near by my device to save some power if it find any device then connection is initiated till then just in ble mode.

Comment: Well, that's exactly how you should do it. BT use much more energy that BLE because it needs to be paired, and to keep the connection alive. So the best practice it to use BLE pretty much all the time, and open a BT connection only when absolutely required, and close it as soon as possible. I am not familiar with nRF51 series but it seams to have extensive libraries so it should be no trouble.